# How do I use `pandas` shift function based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I have a sales data frame consisting of dates, a flag indicating if an item was out of stock and the amount that item was ordered.

To smooth the demand on stock-out days, I take the mean of yesterday's order number, 12 day ago order number and a 3 day moving average.  However, if yesterday's order number, or the order number 12 days ago is also stock out, I need to keep scanning back until I find the first available non-stock out day order number.

Take the sample data below.

```
import pandas as pd

calendar_date = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-01-31")
stock_out_flag = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.]
orders = [45., 51., 48., 52., 51., 47., 49., 48., 51., 51., 49., 49., 52.,
       47., 51., 55., 51., 48., 49., 53., 50., 52., 51., 48., 51., 53.,
       49., 56., 0., 0., 0.]
df =pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'calendar_date':calendar_date, 'stock_out':stock_out_flag,
'orders':orders})
df

calendar_date   stock_out   orders
0   2020-01-01     0.0  45.0
1   2020-01-02     0.0  51.0
2   2020-01-03     0.0  48.0
3   2020-01-04     0.0  52.0
4   2020-01-05     0.0  51.0
5   2020-01-06     0.0  47.0
6   2020-01-07     0.0  49.0
7   2020-01-08     0.0  48.0
8   2020-01-09     0.0  51.0
9   2020-01-10     0.0  51.0
10  2020-01-11     0.0  49.0
11  2020-01-12  -  0.0  49.0
12  2020-01-13     0.0  52.0
13  2020-01-14     0.0  47.0
14  2020-01-15     0.0  51.0
15  2020-01-16     0.0  55.0
16  2020-01-17     0.0  51.0
17  2020-01-18     0.0  48.0
18  2020-01-19     0.0  49.0
19  2020-01-20     0.0  53.0
20  2020-01-21     0.0  50.0
21  2020-01-22     0.0  52.0
22  2020-01-23     0.0  51.0
23  2020-01-24     0.0  48.0
24  2020-01-25     0.0  51.0
25  2020-01-26     0.0  53.0
26  2020-01-27     0.0  49.0
27  2020-01-28     0.0  56.0
28  2020-01-29     1.0  0.0
29  2020-01-30     1.0  0.0
30  2020-01-31     1.0  0.0
```

The last three days of the month are stock outs.  For the date of January 31st, the value for yesterday's order should actually use `56`, the first available non-stock out value. The same value should be used for January 30th.

When using lag values, I usually use `Pandas` shift function.  How could I use the `shift` function based on a condition?

Comment: Hi, could you show what the expected result should look like?